# How to add data in a nested class?

Tags: java, android

I like to create a school directory and each school has its own student. I will have large number of schools and students for each school from **JSON**. My question is how to add data in a 2 level nested class when using **ArrayList**? And can I just use 1 level of nested class for my situation?

I can create **ArrayList** for both schools and students, but they don't seem to know correctly which school has which students.

Thanks.

Data:

```
school id: A1, "Point Grey"
Student name: "Kent", "Age": 43
Student name: "Jane", "Age": 18
Student name: "Winnie", "Age": 19 

school id: B1, "Prince of Wales"
Student name: "Steven", "Age": 11
Student name: "Michelle", "Age": 30
Student name: "Ronald", "Age": 20
```

I have create array list for school and students:

Directory Class:

```
public class DIRECTORY {
    private List<SCHOOL> schools = new ArrayList<>();
    public void setSchools(SCHOOL school) {
        this.schools = (List<SCHOOL>) schools;
    }
    public List<SCHOOL> getSchools() {return this.schools;}
    public void addSchool(String schoolId, String schoolName) {
        SCHOOL school = new SCHOOL();
        school.setSchoolId(schoolId);
        school.setSchoolName(schoolName);
        schools.add(school);
    }
}
```

The School Class:

```
public class SCHOOL {
    private String schoolId;
    private String schoolName;
    private List<STUDENT> students = new ArrayList<>();

    //getter and setter for schoolid and school name 
    public void setStudents(STUDENT students) {
        this.students = (List<STUDENT>) students;
    }
    public List<STUDENT> getStudents() {return this.students;}
    public void addStudent(String names, String age) {
        STUDENT student = new STUDENT();
        student.setNames(names);
        student.setAge(age);
        students.add(student);
}
```

The Student Class:

```
public class STUDENT {
    private String names;
    private String age;
    //getter and setter for name and age

}
```

The main class is:

```
.... 
DIRECTORY directory = new DIRECTORY();
directory.addSchool("A1", "Point Grey");
directory.addSchool("B1", "Prince of Wales");

SCHOOL school = new SCHOOL();

school.addStudent("kent", "43");
school.addStudent("Winnie", "19");
school.addStudent("Jane", "18");

school.addStudent("Steven", "11");
school.addStudent("Michelle", "30");
school.addStudent("Ronald", "20");
...
```

Comment: So what's your question? Are you having an issue with registering students for a particular school, or are you having trouble searching the schools for a particular student?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't know how to manually add students for each school.   I am also wondering whether it is the best approach for my class.

Comment: If you want to associate school with list of students, it can be done by Map<School, List<Student>> schools = new HashMap<School, List<Student>>(); Or you can actually have methods like addStudentToSchool(student, school); also have a findStudentSchool(Student) also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can create arraylist for both schools and students, but they don't
>   seem to know correctly which school has which students.

Easy way:

- Create a `HashMap` in `DIRECTORY` for schools with School ID as Key, and
  SCHOOL as Object.
- Implement `SCHOOL getSchoolById(String id)` method which return SCHOOL 
  object by ID.

Like,

```
public class DIRECTORY {
       private Map<String, SCHOOL> schools = new HashMap<String, SCHOOL>();


        public void setSchools(Map<String, SCHOOL> schoolsMap) {
        this.schools =  schoolsMap;
        }

     public Map<String, SCHOOL> getSchools() {return this.schools;}


     public void addSchool(String schoolId, String schoolName) {
         SCHOOL school = new SCHOOL();
         school.setSchoolId(schoolId);
         school.setSchoolName(schoolName);
         schools.put(schoolId,school);

    }

   public SCHOOL getSchoolById(String schoolId) {
         schools.get(schoolId);
    }

   }
```

Now, your code looks like,

```
DIRECTORY directory = new DIRECTORY();
directory.addSchool("A1", "Point Grey");
directory.addSchool("B1", "Prince of Wales");

SCHOOL schoolA1 = directory.getSchoolById("A1");

schoolA1.addStudent("kent", "43");
schoolA1.addStudent("Winnie", "19");
schoolA1.addStudent("Jane", "18");

SCHOOL schoolB1 = directory.getSchoolById("B1");
schoolB1.addStudent("Steven", "11");
schoolB1.addStudent("Michelle", "30");
schoolB1.addStudent("Ronald", "20");
```

You can also use List with compare methods or other third party library to get school object from school list.